# json and binding methods

Tags: javascript, json, webservice-client, overloading

I have a Person javascript class like

```
function Person(_name, _id, _salary){
    this.Name = _name;
    this.Id = _id;
    this.Salary = _salary;
}
```

**First**, i want to overload constructor function with:

```
function Person( _person ){
    this.Name = _person.Name;
    this.Salary = _person.Salary;
    this.Id = _person.Id;
}
```

***But whatever i do, it goes to the first function ...!?***

**Second**, i have some functions for this javascript class like:

```
Person.prototype.f_IncreaseSalary = function( _percentage ){
    this.Salary *= _percentage;
}
```

What i am doing now is:

1. Send string from web service like `new Person('cem','1000','15000')`
2. eval the string on client side like:

   `dataType:json,
    success:function(msg){ 
       globalObj = eval(msg.d); 
    },`
3. and use the javascript object with its functions. `globalObj.f_IncreaseSalary(0.2);`

But i think i should return the string within json, like:
 `"Person" : {"name":"Cem", "id":1000, "salary":15000 }`

***How can i bind the javascript methods of the Person classs to the json object...?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible in ECMA-/Javascript to "overload" a method/function like this.

A good workaround is to check the arguments object, like

```
function Person(){
   if(typeof arguments[0] === 'object'){
      // addional checks 
      this.Name   = arguments[0].Name;
      this.Salary = arguments[0].Salary;
      // etc.
   }
   else if(arguments.length === 2){
      this.Name   = arguments[0];
      this.Salary = arguments[1];
      // etc.
   }
}
```

I don't think I understand your second question, "how to bind the javascript methods to a json object".

You would need to "parse" the `json` string into a javascript object anyway. That can be done by using `window.JSON.parse(<jsonstring>)` in "modern" browsers. Older browsers (like IE7) need the `json2.js` from [www.json.org](http://www.json.org) to offer the same functionality.